# SQL error using a wild card from a database

Tags: sql, vb.net

[image]

Basically trying to use a wildcard SQL to select and fields that hold the data from txtclass in the homework column of the database. But for some reason what i have done is causing an error. (im am using VB.net)

Comment: The wildcard character is % not * and in any case it should go inside the quotes

Comment: Paste your code in the question. Don't post screenshots of it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL is too generic to be of help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard wildcard  character is the % not the *. It seems that you have taken this query directly from the designer of MS-Access (and perhaps the * is supported by this database system also from ADO.NET).

However there is a bigger problem

The wildcard should be part of the string to match against the LIKE not outside the single quotes

```
 ... LIKE  '%" + txtclass.Text + "'))";
```

Said that you should start immediately to use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation if you want to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems

Comment: thank you, got it going now.i used a hybrid between your solution and the one by graham below.

Answer (score 0):

Use like=* '%txtClass.text%' instead of like=' &txtClass.text&'

Answer (score 0):

Try your SQL statement as:

`SELECT tblQuiz.QuizID, tblQuiz.Classhomework FROM tblQuiz WHERE
tblQuiz.Classhomework LIKE '%' + pupilclass + '%';`

Comment: I tried this and am getting an error on the same line saying no value given for one or more required parameters. I am guessing this is still the SQL giving out the error. Sorry i am really bad with SQl. the only way i was ever taught todo it was by just bringing it over from a query in acess